# WP_User_Query Only Pulling in 1 Result

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to implement a search field which is supposed to find users based on First Name, Last Name and a custom meta of Venue Name.

I've managed to get the field and the WP_User_Query working to an extent, the only problem I seem to be having is that it only ever retrieves 1 result - even though there are multiple results to be shown.

Here's what I've got:

```
<div class="col-12" style="padding-top:0;">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo site_url('/members/'); ?>">
    <div class="user-form">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="member">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search members by first name, surname or venue name..." name="member" id="member" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if( $_GET['member'] ) {

    $search_term = sanitize_text_field( stripslashes( $_GET['member']));    

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'display_name',
    'number'     => 999999,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'venue_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if ( ! empty( $authors ) ) { foreach ( $authors as $author ) 
$author_info = get_userdata( $author->ID );

echo $author_info->first_name;

} 
else {
    echo 'No members found';
}

}
?>
```

I've simplified this, I'm calling in more than just `echo $author_info->first_name;` but I didn't want this to take up too much space.

Really can't work out why it's only retrieving one result.

If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: I would very much recommend having a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281259/93169 - it's not exactly the same problem that you are experiencing, but the answer there is so thorough that it might help you find the problem yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code.

```
// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'display_name',
    'number'     => 999999,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'venue_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        // do something
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($user); 
        echo '</pre>';

    }
} else {
    // no users found
}
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something here Akshay. You're a legend!

It's pulling out two WP_user Objects now, which is awesome. Do you know how I'd get this to echo out in a fashion I could style?

Comment: you can do open close php tag or you can store complete html in one variable and you can echo it out side the loop.

Comment: You're a gent, Akshay. Thank you so much for your help on this, you wouldn't believe the hours I've put into trying to get this to work. It's working like a charm now.